# Multipart form component "cannot POST / divespotform" not working parseInt issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, multipartform-data

I have  a multipart form that I am nearly finished working on that is still not posting to my backend database. Could this be to do with the fact that I am not parsing my two ID fields as ints correctly?

The two text fields and file field look like they are being sent in the request correctly. Is the random pink/blue/black/red symbols the image being sent to the backend? Should my two ID int fields also be showing here as they are on the same form?

The method I have for my Argument 1 is not an object seems to be related to the diveSpotForm line of my handle submit method. Am I passing the form data to the action correctly? I think I might have over complicated the method not posting straight from the form component.

[image]

[image]

form component

```
 const [spot, setSpot] = useState({
        diveLocation: "",
        diveRegionID: parseInt(``),
        diveTypeID: parseInt(``),
        diveSpotDescription: "",
        diveSpotPhotos: "",
        error: ''
    });

    // all onChange functions do the exact same thing, so you only need one
    // pass to a component like onChange={handleChange('typeID')}
    const handleChange = (property) => (e) => {
        setSpot({
            // override the changed property and keep the rest
            ...spot,
            [property]: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    // get access to dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // useEffect with an empty dependency array is the same as componentDidMount
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(requireFieldData());
    }, []);

    const handleSubmitDiveSpot = () => {

        const diveSpotForm = new FormData(document.querySelector("diveSpotForm"))
        console.log('diveSpotForm', diveSpotForm);

        const diveSpot = {
            diveLocation: spot.diveLocation || undefined,
            diveRegionID: spot.diveRegionID || undefined,
            diveSpotTypeID: spot.diveSpotTypeID || undefined,
            diveSpotDescription: spot.diveSpotDescription || undefined,
            diveSpotPhotos: spot.diveSpotPhotos || undefined
        }

        // do some stuff with the form
        createDiveSpot(diveSpot).then((data) => {
            const newSpot = data.error
                ? {...spot, error: data.error}
                : {...spot, error: '', open: true};
            setSpot(newSpot);
            dispatch(addDiveSpot(newSpot));
        })
    }


    const classes = useStyles;

    return (

        <form className="diveSpotForm" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmitDiveSpot}>
            <>
                <Grid container spacing={3}
                      direction="row"
                      justify="center"
                      alignItems="center">
                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                        <PopulateDropdown
                            dataList={diveTypeList}
                            titleProperty={"diveType"} // option label property
                            valueProperty={"diveTypeID"} // option value property
                            name="diveType"
                            placeholder="Dive Type"
                            label="Select Dive Type"
                            value={spot.diveTypeID}
                            onChange={handleChangeInt(parseInt("diveTypeID"))}/>
                    </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <br />
                   ........

                    <br />
                    <Grid item xs={10}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin}>
                            <TextField
                                label="Description"
                                name="diveSpotDescription"
                                value={spot.diveSpotDescription}
                                onChange={handleChange("diveSpotDescription")}
                                multiline
                                rowsMax={6}/>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <br />
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.margin}>
                            <label for="photos">Photo Upload</label>
                            <input
                                type="file"
                                name="photo"
                                value={spot.diveSpotPhotos}
                                onChange={handleChange("diveSpotPhotos")}/>
                        </FormControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <br />
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Submit</Button>
                        <br />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </>
        </form>
```

[image]

action

```
export const createDiveSpot = async (diveSpot) => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:5002/api/divespot/createdivespot', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
            },
            body: new FormData(diveSpot)
        })
        return await response.json()
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

backend

```
exports.createDiveSpot = async (req, res) => {

    const fileNameWithExtension = `${req.file.filename}-${req.file.originalname}`
    const newPath = `./assets/diveSpot/${fileNameWithExtension}`

    fs.rename(req.file.path, newPath, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.send(500)
            }
            diveSpot.create({
                diveLocation: req.body.diveLocation,
                diveRegionID: req.body.diveRegionID,
                diveSpotTypeID: req.body.diveLocation,
                diveSpotDescription: req.body.diveSpotDescription,
                photos: fileNameWithExtension,
            })
                .catch((err) => {
                    res.status(500).send({
                        message: err.message || 'Some error occurred while creating the post.',
                    })
                })
        }
    )}
```

route

```
app.post('/api/divespot/createdivespot', upload.single("diveSpotPhotos"), controller.createDiveSpot);
```

**update**

I have also tried the below handleSubmit method and it is still showing the same two argument 1 is not an object errors. As there are two of them it looks like it could be the two id fields ( which are also not appearing on the payload request in the console).

```
function diveSpotForm(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("diveLocation", spot.diveLocation);
        formData.append("diveRegionID", spot.diveRegionID);
        formData.append("diveSpotTypeID", spot.diveSpotTypeID);
        formData.append("diveSpotDescription", spot.diveSpotDescription);
        formData.append("photos", file);
        axios.post("http://localhost:5002/api/divespot/createdivespot", formData);
    }
```

Comment: your backend is 5002, but you are fetching a absolute path, you should be doing fetch(`localhost:5002/api/divespot/createddivespot`). Your backend service should be something like a nodejs app, listening on 5002, which will interact with your database.

Comment: Cheers, yes I have fixed that part already.

Comment: so was that the issue? If yes then u may close the question

Comment: No i'm still having the same issue.

Comment: your list shows error that you are fetching from 5001.

Comment: and if u send by application/json u need to ensure ur data is JSON.stringify

Comment: My action has the fetch at 5002, should the console log post say the same? It is getting posted from 5001 so it must not be making its way across to the server for some reason.

Comment: I think changing back to JSON.stringify has stopped a different undefined error for diveLocation coming up which was one of the ones that looked like was sending correctly in the request.

Comment: Please update the question and confirm the error + codes you are using. just saw you are using multipart form then you shouldn't be using application/json as content-type

Comment: I'm still seeing a `404 Not Found` error in your screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to figure this out without full code, runnable project etc...
But here are some problems that I could spot in your code.

1. The FormData constructor should get form object as it's argument,
   not an object with values (and you are redefining the same diveSpot variable with no reason - remove this *let diveSpot = new FormData()*).
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData
2. Here is the backend function fixed (at least an attempt)

```
 exports.createDiveSpot = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.diveSpot);

        // if (req.diveSpot == undefined) {
        //     return res.send(`You must select a file.`);
        // }

        return diveSpot.create({
            diveLocation: req.diveSpot.diveLocation,
            diveRegionID: req.diveSpot.diveRegionID,
            diveSpotTypeID: req.diveSpot.diveSpotTypeID,
            diveSpotDescription: req.diveSpot.diveSpotDescription,
            // You want the file location here 
            diveSpotPhotos: "/assets/" + req.file.filename
            ),
        }).then((diveSpot) => {
            fs.writeFileSync(
                __basedir + "/assets/" + req.file.filename,
                req.file.buffer
            );

            return res.json(`File has been uploaded.`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.send(`Error when trying upload images: ${error}`);
    }
};
```

3. You action fixed (Again an attempt)

```
export const createDiveSpot = async (diveSpot) => {
   return fetch('http://localhost:5002/api/divespot/createdivespot', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
            },
            body: new FormData(diveSpot)
        })
.then(response => response.json())
.catch(err => console.log(err));
       
}
```

Comment: The file part is dealt with (i think!) in the backend using Multer. It should be getting stored in a file then the URL posted to Postgres.

Comment: By redefining the dive spot variable twice do you mean the remove the "const diveSpot = {" and just have the createDiveSpot method? or just the formData line?

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept the answer

Comment: On the backend my controller is storing the images and naming them correctly but the url isn't being stored in my postgres table.

Comment: On my front-end I think I have fixed the id int fields by wrapping the e.target.value in parseInt however I am still getting the "FormData constructor: argument 1 is not an object error".

Comment: As the argument is not an object error is appearing twice I still think it could be to do with the two id int fields.